# Running Soap service in process for .NET integration test project

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, integration-testing

I am looking for a way to write integration test project in Visual Studio (.NET C#) that would spawn an existing SOAP service (separate project) running localhost on a defined port with some components being replaced by fakes.

Normally I could just run the service from the project before running the tests, but it would give me more control over the service implementation if the service is run in the same process as the test runner.

1. I could have a separate app.config
2. Through IoC I could replace some real implementations with fakes or mocks.
3. It would be easier to run tests from CI pipeline like TeamCity.

With WCF services it could be kind of achieved using HttsServer class and HttpClient connected directly to the server.

I wonder if anybody did it for SOAP service with all the bindings configured through app.config or in the code.

Please keep it mind that I have all the service reference classes already generated.

Thanks, Radek

Comment: You want to completely mock your running WCF service? Or you want to use IoC to pass in the mocked data to your service?

Comment: I would suggest the latter, use some sort of factory or similar concept and pass it to your service. That way the service code doesn't depend on your implementation. You can then pass it whatever you want and test accordingly.

Comment: No, I prefer not to mock it. There are the number of issues not detected when using mocks, e.g. Xml formatting relates issues. I would rather run the service in process.

Comment: Did this get resolved? Im having the same problem.